How to set up user meta data when a user submits auth0 forms
I have a custom Auth0 form that is displayed when a user signs up to my React application. I created a custom flow that is intended to save some of the input details from the form as a user metadata eg: state, zip code etc. The issue I am having is that I have been unable to set the user meta data when the sign up form is submitted.
I have followed the tutorials on the website and still no progress at all. On further investigation, when I navigated to the executions tabs, in the flows section of the form I found the following (see images below):


I do not understand why I am getting this error because I set up a vault connection that connects to my M2M application for this flow.
How can I resolve this error?
